How to identify the brightness level of an image?
I am doing a project on recognizing photos taken through other devices such as phones, laptops by detecting the black borders around the photo. But there is a problem that the brightness level of each image is always different and if they are affected by bright spots like the image below, it cannot be recognized.
Image:

Here is code:
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set image path
imagePath = "image.jpg"

# Load image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath)
# Deep copy of the input:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Resize because the original image is HUGE:
(h, w) = inputImage.shape[:2]
resizePercent = 10
resizedWidth = int(w * resizePercent / 100)
resizedHeight = int(h * resizePercent / 100)

# Resize image
inputImage = cv2.resize(inputImage, (resizedWidth, resizedHeight), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Get binary image:
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lowerValues = np.array([0, 0, 40])
upperValues = np.array([179, 255, 255])

# Create HSV mask:
hsvImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
tempMask = cv2.inRange(hsvImage, lowerValues, upperValues)

# Apply some morphology:
kernelSize = (3, 3)
morphoKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernelSize)
tempMask = cv2.morphologyEx(tempMask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphoKernel, iterations=1)
plt.imshow(tempMask, cmap='gray')


You can get a brightness image using this equation: Y' = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B. You got the brightness map right?
Plus by using edge detection, such as the Canny algorithm, you can approximate the border edges.
By combining the Canny edge map with the brightness map, you may be able to determine the area you're referring to.

What exactly is the question here? [ask]

that question goes beyond the purpose of SO. you can't solve that at the level of "programming". you need AI/ML to solve this.

that's an unusually high number of upvotes (5 so far) on a question with these tags. what's going on?

user's previous question for context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78996484/how-to-identify-black-border-of-photo-and-remove-this-border
